# calculating durations across variables

Tags: stata

My data in Stata is like:

```
day1    day1_dt     day2    day2_dt     day3    day3_dt     day4    day4_dt     
0       2010-01-02  4       2010-01-03  .       2010-01-04  2       2010-01-05  
.       2011-05-02  3       2011-05-03  4       2011-05-04  4       2011-05-05  
5       2012-01-05  4       2012-01-06  4       2012-01-07  4       2012-01-08  
4       2015-05-02  4       2015-05-03  4       2015-05-04  4       2015-05-05  
1       2009-05-02  4       2009-05-03  0       2009-05-04  4       2009-05-05
```

I want to calculate the following:

1. Duration in days when dayX variable has 4 in them.

I think I solved the first part using following program

```
generate int flg1 =1 if day1 == 4
generate int flg2 =1 if day2 == 4
generate int flg3 =1 if day3 == 4
generate int flg4 =1 if day4 == 4

egen duration = rowtotal(flg*)
```

2. Identify the date where the value of 4 is no more/has changed and record it in end_date

The final data would look like:

```
day1    day1_dt     day2    day2_dt     day3    day3_dt     day4    day4_dt     duration    end_date
0       2010-01-02  4       2010-01-03  .       2010-01-04  2       2010-01-05  1           2010-01-04          
.       2011-05-02  3       2011-05-03  4       2011-05-04  4       2011-05-05  2           .
5       2012-01-05  4       2012-01-06  4       2012-01-07  4       2012-01-08  3           .
4       2015-05-02  4       2015-05-03  4       2015-05-04  4       2015-05-05  4           .
1       2009-05-02  4       2009-05-03  0       2009-05-04  4       2009-05-05  2           .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a typo in the second row in your final example. If not, then please explain why you want `duration` to be 1 and not 2 there.

If it was a typo, then this is the simplest way to do it. Note that it is only the last line of code that is the answer to your question.

```
// This is best practice way of sharing data examples in Stata on StackOverflow

* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input byte day1 int day1_dt byte day2 int day2_dt byte day3 int day3_dt byte day4 int day4_dt
0 18264 4 18265 . 18266 2 18267
. 18749 3 18750 4 18751 4 18752
5 18997 4 18998 4 18999 4 19000
4 20210 4 20211 4 20212 4 20213
1 18019 4 18020 0 18021 4 18022
end
format %tdnn/dd/CCYY day1_dt
format %tdnn/dd/CCYY day2_dt
format %tdnn/dd/CCYY day3_dt
format %tdnn/dd/CCYY day4_dt

// This is your solution

* Count number of day1, day2 etc vars with value 4
egen duration = anycount(day?), values(4)
```

Comment: This answers OP's Question 1. Question 2: Keeping the same layout, the last date with value 4 seems harder to calculate unless  with a loop.

Comment: Yes the typo has been fixed. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: My contribution was writing `anycount()` originally!

Answer (score 0):

From a Stata point of view you seem to be holding panel or longitudinal data in a wide layout. As you are finding out, that makes even simple tasks quite complicated. I recommend changing to long layout with a `reshape`.

See the Stata tag wiki for how to give data examples as Stata code (short explanation: use the `dataex` command). Your example is fairly clear but requires a guess at what kind of date you have, as the display format could be YMD or YDM. I guessed one way, but the principles are the same the other way. If your date variables are really strings, you need to push them through `daily()` to do anything useful.

Script and output follow. You'll want to assign a display format to `enddate` as well.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input byte(day1 day2 day3 day4) float(day1_dt day2_dt day3_dt day4_dt)
0 4 . 2 18264 18265 18266 18267
. 3 4 4 18749 18750 18751 18752
5 4 4 4 18997 18998 18999 19000
4 4 4 4 20210 20211 20212 20213
1 4 0 4 18019 18020 18021 18022
end
format %tdCY-N-D day1_dt
format %tdCY-N-D day2_dt
format %tdCY-N-D day3_dt 
format %tdCY-N-D day4_dt

gen long id = _n 
reshape long day day@_dt, i(id)

egen duration = total(day == 4), by(id)

egen enddate = max(cond(day == 4, day_dt, .)), by(id)
egen whenlast = max(day_dt), by(id)
replace enddate = . if enddate == whenlast 

list, sepby(id)
```

```
. * Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
. clear

. input byte(day1 day2 day3 day4) float(day1_dt day2_dt day3_dt day4_dt)

         day1      day2      day3      day4    day1_dt    day2_dt    day3_dt    day4_dt
  1. 0 4 . 2 18264 18265 18266 18267
  2. . 3 4 4 18749 18750 18751 18752
  3. 5 4 4 4 18997 18998 18999 19000
  4. 4 4 4 4 20210 20211 20212 20213
  5. 1 4 0 4 18019 18020 18021 18022
  6. end

. format %tdCY-N-D day1_dt

. format %tdCY-N-D day2_dt

. format %tdCY-N-D day3_dt 

. format %tdCY-N-D day4_dt

. 
. gen long id = _n 

. reshape long day day@_dt, i(id)
(j = 1 2 3 4)

Data                               Wide   ->   Long
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Number of observations                5   ->   20          
Number of variables                   9   ->   4           
j variable (4 values)                     ->   _j
xij variables:
                     day1 day2 ... day4   ->   day
            day1_dt day2_dt ... day4_dt   ->   day_dt
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

. 
. egen duration = total(day == 4), by(id)

. 
. egen enddate = max(cond(day == 4, day_dt, .)), by(id)

. egen whenlast = max(day_dt), by(id)

. replace enddate = . if enddate == whenlast 
(16 real changes made, 16 to missing)

. 
. list, sepby(id)

     +------------------------------------------------------------+
     | id   _j   day       day_dt   duration   enddate   whenlast |
     |------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |  1    1     0   2010-01-02          1     18265      18267 |
  2. |  1    2     4   2010-01-03          1     18265      18267 |
  3. |  1    3     .   2010-01-04          1     18265      18267 |
  4. |  1    4     2   2010-01-05          1     18265      18267 |
     |------------------------------------------------------------|
  5. |  2    1     .   2011-05-02          2         .      18752 |
  6. |  2    2     3   2011-05-03          2         .      18752 |
  7. |  2    3     4   2011-05-04          2         .      18752 |
  8. |  2    4     4   2011-05-05          2         .      18752 |
     |------------------------------------------------------------|
  9. |  3    1     5   2012-01-05          3         .      19000 |
 10. |  3    2     4   2012-01-06          3         .      19000 |
 11. |  3    3     4   2012-01-07          3         .      19000 |
 12. |  3    4     4   2012-01-08          3         .      19000 |
     |------------------------------------------------------------|
 13. |  4    1     4   2015-05-02          4         .      20213 |
 14. |  4    2     4   2015-05-03          4         .      20213 |
 15. |  4    3     4   2015-05-04          4         .      20213 |
 16. |  4    4     4   2015-05-05          4         .      20213 |
     |------------------------------------------------------------|
 17. |  5    1     1   2009-05-02          2         .      18022 |
 18. |  5    2     4   2009-05-03          2         .      18022 |
 19. |  5    3     0   2009-05-04          2         .      18022 |
 20. |  5    4     4   2009-05-05          2         .      18022 |
     +------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Yes, I wish the data was in long format. Unfortunately, the data is too big(both long and wide) for the transposing.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sequel to the answer by @TheIceBear showing how to answer Question 2 while keeping the same layout.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input byte(day1 day2 day3 day4) float(day1_dt day2_dt day3_dt day4_dt)
0 4 . 2 18264 18265 18266 18267
. 3 4 4 18749 18750 18751 18752
5 4 4 4 18997 18998 18999 19000
4 4 4 4 20210 20211 20212 20213
1 4 0 4 18019 18020 18021 18022
end
format %tdCY-N-D day1_dt
format %tdCY-N-D day2_dt
format %tdCY-N-D day3_dt 
format %tdCY-N-D day4_dt


gen enddate = . 

* 1/4 is contingent on day*_dt running over 1 to 4 
* and on those variables being in date order 
forval j = 1/4 { 
    replace enddate = day`j'_dt if day`j' == 4 
}

egen whenlast = rowmax(day*_dt) 

replace enddate = . if enddate == whenlast 

format enddate whenlast %td 

list enddate whenlast
```

Comment: This is quite interesting as well. Thanks!